# Style sheets in Qt for Nokia

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, widget

I am developing an application for Nokia devices using Qtcreator. But the problem is that the UI is not so attractive. In the desktop apps we can use Style sheet for changing the design & color of the widgets but can we use the same for the Nokia also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey sample example for how to add style sheets s [here](http://qt-articles.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-add-stylesheet-for-button-in-qt.html).

Answer (score 1):

Might want to try Google first: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/stylesheet.html

Comment: Ya I know about the stylesheet & have used them for desktop apps but I just want to know if it will work for Nokia devices also or not...

Comment: Well, since the only documented limitation is custom `QStyle`, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work with `QS60Style`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you [definitely can](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_make_a_stylesheet_in_Qt_for_Symbian._Part_1) use Qt StyleSheets with the Nokia Qt SDK for Symbian/Maemo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt >= 4.7 you may be interested in [Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtquick.html), which is technology for creating UI's.